# sql server passing error to application

Tags: sql-server

I need to pass the error to the application. I wrote the stored procedures as below:
Does it pass the error to the application or we need to do the something more?

Eg.

```
create procedure insert_emp 
as
  begin try
       begin tran
         insert into emp values(..........)
       commit;
   end try

   begin catch
     if @@trancount > 0
     rollback
     declare @errMessage varchar(2000),
     declare @errNumber int
     select @errMessage = error_message(), @errNumber = error_number()
     raiserror(@errMessage, @errNumber,1)
   end catch
```

If I need to pass 0 if there is no error and a error number if there was a error, how to do it using raiserror? How can we log the error to error_table using raiserror? More importantly can above eg. pass the error to an application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass `raiserror(@errMessage, @errNumber,1)`. The arguments for [RAISERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) are message id, **severity**, state. You are passing @errNumber for *severity*, which is incorrect.

You should instead raise a custom error and pass the caught exception information in the error message as message format inserts:

```
RAISERROR(N'insert_emp: Error %i: %s', 16, 1, @errNumber, @errMessage);
```

You should use severity 16 for errors that you want to throw a SqlException in the client side processing (or other exception, according to the client access technology used).

You should use severity 1 for informational messages.

Answer (score 1):

`RAISERROR` will pass the error to the client.

If you want to log the error in the database, do that first in the `catch` area, and then call `raiserror`.

If you do not want to pass the error to the client (I have worked at companies who prefer to return error codes) then instead of calling `raiserror`, you can simply return a non-zero value from the procedure, like this:

```
RETURN -1
```